# How to create Unit Test to a MongoRepository class containing a MongoTemplate instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have a Java Spring boot application, and I need to create unit tests for it. I pretend to start the test classes with my repository class, but I'm having certain trouble on it. All my use cases, call my Repository class methods. My repository class is something like this:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
     private final UserDao userDao;
     private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

     @Override
    public Optional<User> findUserByEmailAndCompany(String email, String companyID) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("enabled").is(true)
                .and("companyId").is(companyID)
                .and("email").is(email));
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class));
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble because I'm not quite sure on how to test the method with the MongoTemplate calls.

I tried to implement the code injecting the MongoTemplate in the test class, I was getting the `mongoTemplate is null` error, but now I'm getting something else: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`.

My test class is the following:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
class UserRepositoryImplTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should get user successfully from database")
    void findUserByEmailAndCompanyCase1() {
        String companyID = "";
        String email = "test@gmail.com";

        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("enabled").is(true)
                .and("companyId").is(companyID )
                .and(email).is(email));
        Optional<User> result = Optional.ofNullable(this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class));
        assertThat(result.isPresent()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Any advice is welcome, I'm new to unit testing so I'm trying to learn even the concepts. For example, I'm still unsure whether I should really be testing this repository class instead of just the use cases, but I read somewhere that I should test any class which the was written by me, the dev. So my other worry was, test a method that directly deals with the database. I found some examples with SQL database, using the `@DataJpaTest` but not much about MongoDb.

I tried to keep the question short, but any needed new info about the code I can bring to here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **@SpringBootTest** you must use **@MockBean** so that with this annotation the context can be loaded.